# Creating the first controller in Symfony

Tags: php, symfony

I have just started to learn Symfony. The fact is that I do things and they work but I don't understand what I am doing and that must be the wrong way starting to learn something.

Here is a simple controller:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Controller;

use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;

class HelloController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/hello")
     */
    public function helloAction() {
        return $this->render('', array());
    }
}
```

So in this case when I type

```
/**
 * @Route("/hello")
 */
```

my editor automatically adds this line of code:

```
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
```

What is that doing?

I have learned that namespaces must match the directory path but there is no way I could find that path in my Symfony project. So is it outside of my project? If so, this will be good to know in case I want to upload my project on the web server.

I would appreciate if someone could please explain this "mystery".

Comment: The `Route` class is inside the vendor folder, where the deps of your project are.

Comment: You just defined a parameter `@Route` to your `helloAction()`. To work properly, it need the class `Route` located in `Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration`. This is why it was added.

Answer (score 1):

Your IDE just added the dependency to `Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;`, which is required to use the `@Route` annotation.

It is placed under the `vendor/` directory, which of course you will need to upload along with your sources.